# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, why?

Tags: java, swing

I create a button to copy the selected pixel color.
It works fine if I click the picture(get the pixel value) first, then click the "copy" button. But if I click the "copy" button first, I will receive this error.
Any thoughts?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pixel value is null
    at a9.ImageEditorController.copy(ImageEditorController.java:81)
    at a9.PixelInspectorTool.actionPerformed(PixelInspectorTool.java:95)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

---

```
public void copy() {
    Pixel selectedB = model.getSelected();
    if (selectedB == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot be null");  //line 81
    }
    PaintBrushToolUI pbtUI = (PaintBrushToolUI) paint_brush_tool.getUI();
    pbtUI.changeView(selectedB);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    for (ToolButtonListener t : tList) {
        t.copy();         // this is line 95
        System.out.println("Copying");
    }
}
```

Comment: Clearly the result of `model.getSelected()` is `null` in that case, right?

Comment: `model.getSelected()` is returning null, obviously.  Unless you provide us with the type of `model`, it’s going to be nearly impossible to explain why it is returning null.

Comment: Apparently clicking the red button sets the value of `model.selected`. And it's null when you don't click the button, and click copy first. So... which part don't you understand?

Comment: I am sorry if I did not clear my question. So the issue is when I click the button first, I get the error says"the pixel value is null". However, it works fine when I click the pixel first, then click the button(which is obviously, because I get the pixel value first and then copy it, so I don't have the error).

Answer (score 0):

Well actually you get this error message because You throw it exactly here:

```
 if (selectedB == null) {
   // code bellow throws your exception...
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot be null");  //line 81
}
```

To solve your problem you can check if your model is null here:

```
 for(ToolButtonListener t:tList) {
     //check here if it's null for example 
    if(model.getSelected() != null){
       t.copy();         // this is line 95
       System.out.println("Copying");
    }
}
```

Or you can make the copy method to check if object is null like this:

```
public void copy() {
Pixel selectedB= model.getSelected();
if (selectedB != null) {
//    throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot be null");  //line 81

  PaintBrushToolUI pbtUI = (PaintBrushToolUI)paint_brush_tool.getUI();
  pbtUI.changeView(selectedB);
}
```

}
This error occurs because before you click that other button to create color the first one(copy button) doesn't have "source" to copy from. 
You can also make the copy button inactive until you click the other button. There are various solutions for your problem(probably a lot better than mine) and it all depends on what effect you want to achieve.